# A question about the definition of stability of a critical point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

From an introductory chapter to differential equations:

> > A critical point, say, $x_0$, of the differential equation $$\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)\tag{1}$$ is called stable if given $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$, such that for all $t \geq t_0,$ $\lVert x(t)−x_0(t)\rVert< \varepsilon$, whenever $\lVert x(t_0) − x_0(t_0) \rVert< \delta,$ where $x(t)$ is a solution of (1).

I understand that "for all $t \ge t_0,$ $\lVert x(t)−x_0(t)\rVert< \varepsilon$" is a way of writing that the value of $x(t)$ is not going away from $x_0$. But why is the "whenever $\lVert x(t_0) − x_0(t_0) \rVert< \delta$" useful?

Comment: Are you sure it is not $t\ge t_c$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The delta part is necessary because it establishes that $x_0$ is a critical point if the subsequent condition holds, *no matter how near or far the critical point is away from the solution*. That's what makes it critical. It could be super close or super far away. All we know is that if the downstream solutions are always relatively bounded, then the point is a critical point.

Comment: If we set time to $t_0$ we will see, that initial condition should suffice to both inequalities: $\lVert x(0)-x_0 \rVert < \delta$ and $\lVert x(0) - x_0 \rVert < \varepsilon$, so $\delta < \varepsilon$. The best explanation for this condition would be an example that shows some special behaviour of trajectories with respect to initial neighbourhood.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the condition "whenever $\| x(t_0)−x_0(t_0) \|<\delta$" is useful.

A critical point, say $x_0$, is stable means that if a point $x(t_0)$ is near $x_0$ at $t_0$, then for all $t \geq t_0$, the corresponding solutions $x(t)$ and $x_0(t)$ starting from $x(t_0)$ and $x_0(t_0)$ at $t$ are near too.

In mathematical language, the definition is

"A critical point, say, $x_0$, of the differential equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=f(x)(1)$ is called stable if given $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$, such that for all $t \geq t_0$,$\| x(t)−x_0(t) \| <\varepsilon$, whenever $\| x(t_0)−x_0(t_0) \| < \delta$, where $x(t)$ is a solution of $(1)$."

Comment: Awww ok, I did not get the being near at t0 part. It makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I've mentioned that there's some peculiarity behind the definition of Lyapunov stability, especially the part that was asked by topic starter.
Consider the following system:

[image]

This is just a sample of dynamics, but you can extend it to the whole plane. And of course there'll be a critical point inside this family of closed curves.

So, you look at picture; what associations do you have? Trajectories don't go to infinity, that's good, and they have a behaviour that resembles "staying in the neighbourhood of critical point", something stable. 
It's good definitions try to catch the most important examples which behaviour we want describe. I think that you agree that behaviour in this example should be called stable too (like an example of conservative harmonic oscillator $x'' = -\omega^2 x$).

Now, if we try to remove the part that you was asking about, we'll find that our new definition don't capture this case: some trajectories that begin in $\epsilon$-ball go out of it. And that's bad: definition don't work. But look, if we have two neighbourhoods (as in original definition), we can capture this example: for every neighbourhood in this example you can know the maximal distance along all trajectories from origin. And here begins the $\epsilon-\delta$ interplay.